# After tapping the screen should make textView invisible android

Tags: android

I am doing a Dictionary Application. After taping anywhere on the screen, the textView in the xml page must be visible or invisible.

Comment: Can't you call `setVisibility()` method run time?

Comment: Post more detail please.

Comment: Your whole UI must be inside a parent Layout, set OnClick listener to that layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FindViewById your layout and onTouchListner make yout TextView Invisible

eg.

```
LinearLayout lnlay = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearlayout_id); //your layout
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.yourTextView_id); //TextView you want to make invisible on Tapping 

        lnlay .setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                 textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                      }
             }
```

This should work

Answer (score 0):

Find your *TextView* by using *findViewById(...)* and *setVisibility(GONE)* or *INVISIBLE*, and *VISIBLE* to get it back.

Do not forget to keep the TextView in a variable, it's never a good idea to use findViewById(...) more than once for the same view, it's too much work for the framework to find a view by id.